# Execute ping command in php and get interactive output on webpage

Tags: php, bash, web-services, ping

I tried to run ping command using php:

```
<?php
    $response = shell_exec('ping -c 4 '. $_POST['host']);
    echo "<div class=\"response\">".$response."</div>";
?>
```

But I post hostname from input box and then run this php script. This works but show output only when command run successfully not interactive as

https://w3dt.net/tools/ping

When I give "www.google.com" it shows the results in interactive manners. Can you please help me to build interactive as **w3dt.net** or suggest me any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

1. The tool you linked to uses WebSockets to render an "interactive" output.
2. You should never pass any unchecked user input into a shell_exec() call, as that will enable anyone to run almost any shell command (by specifying, say, "google.com && rm -rf /" as the hostname).

Comment: I can understand. Can you please give little help about WebSockets

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/optimization/creating-real-time-applications-with-php-and-websockets.html